# Getting an error while adding filter_path to ElasticSearch query: error [bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: elasticsearch

> I have Elasticsearch query function, getting an error as a malformed query. When I am adding filter_path key inside the query builder then it throws error Please see my query:

```
  def query(options = {})

    aggregations = {}

    buckets = {}
    buckets_for_unique_users buckets, aggregations

    filters = []
    filters << time_filter(options)

    query = {
      query: { bool: { filter: filters }, filter_path: ['unique_users,unique_users.user_details.hits.hits._id'] },
      aggregations: buckets
    }
    query
  end
```

> Update:
>   Below is the search query function

```
def user
      @builder = ::Order::Report::UserBuilder.new @frequency, @offset, @periods

      query = @builder.query restaurant_id: @restaurant_id, channel_id: @channel_id

      @response = Payments::Order.__elasticsearch__.search query

    end
```

Comment: This is because you cannot specify `filter_path` within the body of the query, you need to pass that as argument to the search call.

Comment: @Val I have added the search call function (You can see user function) when I have merged the filter_path to the query then I got the same error. 
query.merge!(:filter_path => ["unique_users,unique_users.user_details.hits.hits._id"]) But it was not working.